# sed to search for multiple words and remove those lines

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a master file with more than 50000 lines and my requirement is to remove around 20000 lines from actual file. For this I used grep -vE command which is showing a error as too many arguments. I am using sed command to remove those using for loop. But it is taking so much time to remove as 20000 sed commands are going to initialise. I need help in doing it as fast as possible.

```
for i in `cat 20000-words.txt`; do 
    sed -i -e "/$i/ d" 50000-lines.txt
done
```

Comment: @Networker I don't find that necessary.

Comment: fgrep -vf to_exlude.txt original.txt

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru Are those words separated by newlines?

Comment: @konsolebox Yes , It is .

Comment: This question was asked simultaneously here and on the [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146359/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-f` option of `grep` to use the word list as the pattern list:

```
grep -v -f 20000-words.txt 50000-lines.txt
```

You might also need the `-w` or `-F` switches to match whole words or disable regex interpretation of words, respectivelly.

Comment: If both files are sorted (it seems they may be some sort of dictionary or word list, so they might be), `comm -13 20000-words.txt 50000-lines.txt` would be a reasonable alternative as well (unless I've misunderstood, and the `50000-lines.txt` file actually has more than one word per line - that's a bit unclear).